# Injecting text when content is copied from a web page

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I ran into a a site that injects a "Read More: " line at the end of any text that you highlight and copy from it's pages.

I've never seen this before, and without severely digging into their code, I can't find the code that does this.

Anyone know how this is done?

Example: http://peaceful-parenting.suite101.com/article.cfm/how_to_keep_kids_from_climbing_on

Copy a paragraph of text, and paste it into another application, and there will be a "read more" line afterwards.

Comment: Just don't do this, please do not do it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Suite101 is using a 3rd party service called [Tynt](http://www.tynt.com/).

Tynt's JavaScript snippet is located at http://tcr.tynt.com/javascripts/Tracer.js

I explored the source for you (with some help from the [Online JavaScript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)).

So here's what's happening:

- the code activates on events like mouseup, mousedown, and copy (in the `startListeningForTraces` function)
- if the user selected a range of text, then it:

  - creates the HTML for an attribution link, plus optional CC license URL
  - appends this HTML to the selection, placing it inside a zero-size `<div>` (to keep it invisible on-screen)
  - reports what was copied back to Tynt's servers

Tynt's code does a tremendous amount of work to make this work seamlessly across browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is tynt.com, which is some sort of tracer for text being copied off their page.

From the tynt.com site

> Tracer automatically adds a link back to your site when content is copied and pasted.
>     Read more: http://tracer.tynt.com/features-and-benefits-of-tracer#ixzz0MgaE6z6y
>     Under Creative Commons License: Attribution No Derivatives

Heck... it just added the read more link and the CC license stuff to the text I copied from the tynt.com site.