# How to add extra info to copied web text

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Some websites now use a JavaScript service from [Tynt](http://www.tynt.com) that appends text to copied content.

If you copy text from a site using this and then paste you get a link to the original content at the bottom of the text.

Tynt also tracks this as it happens. It's a neat trick well done.

Their script for doing this is impressive - rather than try to manipulate the clipboard (which only older versions of IE lets them do by default and which should always be turned off) they manipulate the actual selection.

So when you select a block of text the extra content is added as a hidden `<div>` included in your selection. When you paste the extra style is ignored and the extra link appears.

This is actually fairly easy to do with simple blocks of text, but a nightmare when you consider all the selections possible across complex HTML in different browsers.

I'm developing a web application - I don't want anyone to be able to track the content copied and I would like the extra info to contain something contextual, rather than just a link. Tynt's service isn't really appropriate in this case.

Does anyone know of an open source JavaScript library (maybe a jQuery plug in or similar) that provides similar functionality but that doesn't expose internal application data?

Comment: Have a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344588/how-does-financial-times-add-a-disclaimer-when-pasting-text/6347927#6347927. It is done very similarly as you proposed

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203082/injecting-text-when-content-is-copied-from-a-web-page

Comment: Please don't do this.  PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE just don't.

Comment: @couchand why not? I get how annoying this is on spam sites, but this is for an application that can be used for citations and where the internal data is sensitive. That's why I didn't want to use Tynt.

Comment: Alternative: https://github.com/tovic/sticky-attribution

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? As a user, I hate it and I will port this anger into your product: [Don't touch my clipboard!](https://alexanderell.is/posts/taking-over-my-clipboard/)

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com this was a decade ago, but it was a requirement - the documents they were copying from were legal and it was a big help for them to automatically include the citation link back to the source. This isn't something I'd do on general sites - the users understood that the copied quote had to cite exactly where it came from.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

## 2022 Update

More complex solution that handles rich text formatting. The 2020 solution is still relevant if you only deal with plain text.

```js
const copyListener = (event) => {
  const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
    rangeContents = range.cloneContents(),
    pageLink = `Read more at: ${document.location.href}`,
    helper = document.createElement("div");

  helper.appendChild(rangeContents);

  event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", `${helper.innerText}\n${pageLink}`);
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/html", `${helper.innerHTML}<br>${pageLink}`);
  event.preventDefault();
};
document.addEventListener("copy", copyListener);
```

```css
#richText {
  width: 415px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#richText:empty:before {
  content: "Paste your copied text here";
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<h4>Rich text:</h4>
<p>Lorem <u>ipsum</u> dolor sit <b>amet</b>, consectetur <i>adipiscing</i> elit.</p>
<h4>Plain text editor:</h4>
<textarea name="textarea" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Paste your copied text here"></textarea>
<h4>Rich text editor:</h4>
<div id="richText" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

---

## 2020 Update

Solution that works on all *recent* browsers.

Note that this solution will strip rich text formatting (such as bold and italic), even when pasting into a rich text editor.

```js
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  const pagelink = `\n\nRead more at: ${document.location.href}`;
  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', document.getSelection() + pagelink);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit <b>amet</b>, consectetur <i>adipiscing</i> elit.<br/>
<textarea name="textarea" rows="7" cols="50" placeholder="paste your copied text here"></textarea>
```

---

### *[Older post - before the 2020 update]*

There are two main ways to add extra info to copied web text.

1. Manipulating the selection

---

The idea is to watch for the `copy event`, then append a hidden container with our extra info to the `dom`, and extend the selection to it.
This method is adapted from [this article](http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/) by *c.bavota*. Check also [*jitbit*'s version](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/230-javascript-injecting-extra-info-to-copy-pasted-text/) for more complex case.

- **Browser compatibility**: All major browsers, IE > 8.
- **Demo**: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jp6nhmxf/).
- **Javascript code**:

```
    function addLink() {
        //Get the selected text and append the extra info
        var selection = window.getSelection(),
            pagelink = '<br /><br /> Read more at: ' + document.location.href,
            copytext = selection + pagelink,
            newdiv = document.createElement('div');

        //hide the newly created container
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

        //insert the container, fill it with the extended text, and define the new selection
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 100);
    }

    document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

2. Manipulating the clipboard

---

The idea is to watch the `copy event` and directly modify the clipboard data. This is possible using the `clipboardData` property. Note that this property is available in all major browsers in `read-only`; the `setData` method is only available on IE.

- **Browser compatibility**: IE > 4.
- **Demo**: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m56af0je/).
- **Javascript code**:

```
    function addLink(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var pagelink = '\n\n Read more at: ' + document.location.href,
            copytext =  window.getSelection() + pagelink;

        if (window.clipboardData) {
            window.clipboardData.setData('Text', copytext);
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

Comment: Cheers! Unfortunately we need it working in IE, but that isn't a bad start.

Comment: @Keith did You find solution both for IE and normal browsers? Without Flash solution.

Comment: There should be a workaround for "<pre>" tags, a smoother version of this script is [here](http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/230-javascript-injecting-extra-info-to-copypasted-text/)

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Yosemite. Once I mess with `selection` in the copy handler in any way, nothing gets copied at all in Chrome/Firefox (the previous value remains in the clipboard); in Safari the clipboard is cleared but nothing new appears there.

Comment: EDIT: oh, it works but the element cannot have `visibility: hidden` set. Weird.

Comment: Note that "Manipulating the clipboard" works prefectly in FireFox, Chrome and Safari if you change `window.clipboardData` to `event.clipboardData`. IE (v11 too) don't support `event.clipboardData` http://jsfiddle.net/m56af0je/8/

Comment: If you are using Google Analytics etc, you can even fire off an event to log what users are copying from your site. Interesting

Comment: The first option ignores the new line characters of the copied text.

Comment: Approach 1 on Edge works but has a graphical defect. When you copy, the line `selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);` makes your page scroll to the bottom. This happens because the `newdiv` element is appended to the bottom. For avoiding the unwanted scroll, append the `newdiv` to the element that triggered the copy (jquery): `$(e.target).after($(newdiv))`

Comment: It's kind of disturbing to be able to do this but not being able to do it with a simpler function.

Comment: @geedubb how can we fire off an event to log what users aer copying from the site?

Comment: Can we have the text inserted when just more than a certain number of characters are copied?

Comment: typo: `e` should be `event`

Answer (score 8):

This is a vanilla javascript solution from a modified solution above but supports more browsers (cross browser method)

```
function addLink(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pagelink = '\nRead more: ' + document.location.href,
    copytext =  window.getSelection() + pagelink;
    clipdata = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    if (clipdata) {
        clipdata.setData('Text', copytext);
    }
}
document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

Comment: Note that this solution will strip rich text formatting (such as bold and italic).

Answer (score 3):

The shortest version for jQuery that I tested and is working is:

```
jQuery(document).on('copy', function(e)
{
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var copyFooter = 
        "<br /><br /> Source: <a href='" + document.location.href + "'>" + document.location.href + "</a><br />© YourSite";
  var copyHolder = $('<div>', {html: sel+copyFooter, style: {position: 'absolute', left: '-99999px'}});
  $('body').append(copyHolder);
  sel.selectAllChildren( copyHolder[0] );
  window.setTimeout(function() {
      copyHolder.remove();
  },0);
});
```

Comment: where is the code which actually copies the result to the clipboard?

Comment: @vsync I believe this just adds functionality just before the copying takes place (which is done by the system when the user initiates it).

Comment: @vsync - as TerraRich said, I tried to respond for the question, which was about adding extra info into copied text, so solution covers this part only.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plugin in jquery to do that
https://github.com/niklasvh/jquery.plugin.clipboard
From the project readme
"This script modifies the contents of a selection prior to a copy event being called, resulting in the copied selection being different from what the user selected.

This allows you to append/prepend content to the selection, such as copyright information or other content.

Released under MIT License"

Comment: That looks very promising. It uses inline styles which we don't allow with our CSP, but it could potentially be adapted. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Improving on the answer, restore selection after the alterations to prevent random selections after copy.

```
function addLink() {
    //Get the selected text and append the extra info
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
        pagelink = '<br /><br /> Read more at: ' + document.location.href,
        copytext = selection + pagelink,
        newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); // edited according to @Vokiel's comment

    //hide the newly created container
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    //insert the container, fill it with the extended text, and define the new selection
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }, 100);
}

document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa

There should be `var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);`

Comment: Restoring text selection is a good idea, otherwise, it breaks default browser behaviour.

Comment: "Improving on the answer"... improving on which answer?

Answer (score 3):

Improvement for 2018

```js
document.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', $('<div/>').html(selection + "").text() + "\n\n" + 'Source: ' + document.location.href);
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', selection + '<br /><br /><a href="' + document.location.href + '">Source</a>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Example text with <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i>. Try copying and pasting me into a rich text editor.</p>
```

Comment: When you copy-paste you lose formatting (_<a>_, _<img>_, _<b>_ and other tags). It's better to get HTML code of selected text. Use _**getSelectionHtml()**_ function from this answer:  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177234/4177020] And now you can replace this string
`var selection = window.getSelection();`
by this one:
`var selection = getSelectionHtml();`

Comment: If you paste into a rich text editor, you get a pretty link with the caption "Source", which is nice. However, it doesn't preserve the rich text formatting of the original text. Also, I'm not sure why `$('<div/>').html(selection + "").text()` is needed, `selection.toString()` is plain text to begin with.

Comment: Also, this part should be escaped properly: `<a href="' + document.location.href + '">`, right now, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Also a little shorter solution:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ )
    {
    function addLink()
    {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Source: <a href='" + document.location.href + "'>" + document.location.href + "</a><br />© text is here";
    var div = $( '<div>', {style: {position: 'absolute', left: '-99999px'}, html: sel + pagelink} );
    $( 'body' ).append( div );
    sel.selectAllChildren( div[0] );
    div.remove();
    }



document.oncopy = addLink;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's a compilation of 2 answers above + compatibility with Microsoft Edge.**

I've also added a restore of the original selection at the end, as it is expected by default in any browser.

```
function addCopyrightInfo() {
    //Get the selected text and append the extra info
    var selection, selectedNode, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount) {
            selectedNode = selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            container.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    }
    else {
        console.debug("The text [selection] not found.")
        return;
    }

    // Save current selection to resore it back later.
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    if (!html)
        html = '' + selection;

    html += "<br/><br/><small><span>Source: </span><a target='_blank' title='" + document.title + "' href='" + document.location.href + "'>" + document.title + "</a></small><br/>";
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    //hide the newly created container
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    // Insert the container, fill it with the extended text, and define the new selection.
    selectedNode.appendChild(newdiv); // *For the Microsoft Edge browser so that the page wouldn't scroll to the bottom.

    newdiv.innerHTML = html;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        selectedNode.removeChild(newdiv);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range); // Restore original selection.
    }, 5); // Timeout is reduced to 10 msc for Microsoft Edge's sake so that it does not blink very noticeably.  
}

document.addEventListener('copy', addCopyrightInfo);
```