# Remove external html tags when copying into an iframe text editor

Tags: html, iframe, browser

I have made my custom iframe based text editor from scratch. I am looking to implement two features now. Here is the iframe :

```
 <div id="iframe-container" style="height: 200px; width : 450px ; border:1px solid #1d1d1d;">
                                         <iframe id="wysiwygtextfield" onload = 'return iframevents(); ' frameborder="0" style="height:   100%; width:100%;" scrolling="no" >
                                            <html>
                                               <head>

                                                     </head>
                                                <body>
                                                    <br/>

                                                 </body>
                                              </html>
                                            </iframe>
                                      </div>
```

At times when copy pasting from the web the text contains styling rules of it's own.When the text is pasted into a regular input box the styling disappears on it's own, however the iframe tends to retain the styling. Is there a way to copy paste into a iframe without the HTML tags?

Comment: You need to strip the HTML tags with some Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using regex:

`var String = Sample.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");`

[Prevent copying text in web-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957443/prevent-copying-text-in-web-page)

Sample is the text being loaded in iframe

replace is a function that changes the matched text to another, which is nothing `""`.

then append the modified text.

You may have to do this.

- onchange event select content of textarea
- run the replace function
- done. :D