# Cannot copy option set value using mouse in angular material

Tags: angular-material, copy, option-set

When I set mat-select as disabled I cannot copy value from this field using mouse. When I am trying to copy value from other disabled fields like text input this problem doesn't exist. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So base on this answer: [Prevent copying text in web-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957443/prevent-copying-text-in-web-page) I added this code to my main style.css file and it works now

```
.mat-select-disabled .mat-select-trigger {
  user-select: all !important;
}
```