# Copy hidden things

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add extra info to copied web text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text)

I tried to copy a text in a website and when I pasted it, a sentence came out after the text.
This is the website:  http://www.markrushworth.com/css-center-unordered-list-ulli-based-menu/
Try to copy `#footer{text-align:center;list-style:none}#footer li{display:inline}`
And paste it in notepad.

I want to know how to do this.

Comment: It is done using a plugin in `Wordpress` Check This http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/copy-link/

Comment: see page source of that link and u'll get it

Comment: There is a related question on how to copy to the clipboard using javascript. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript). The site you refered to binds to the copy event using jQuery > $('body').bind('copy', function(evt) {
> ..... > });

Comment: The [element.oncopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.oncopy) method is one way to do it. **Update:**
Here is another similar question with a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript