# Add extra info (copyright notice/read more link) to copied text and preserve formatting (line breaks and color)

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to add a read more link to my copied text but **the line breaks and formatting are ignored**:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
function addLink() {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;body&#39;)[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
  var pagelink = &quot;<br/><br/> Mai multe Bancuri pe: http://bancuricubarbatisifemei.blogspot.com/ <br/>&quot;; // change this if you want
    var copytext = selection + pagelink;
    var newdiv = document.createElement(&#39;div&#39;);
    newdiv.style.position=&#39;absolute&#39;;
    newdiv.style.left=&#39;-99999px&#39;;
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
    },0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>
```

How to preserve them?

Comment: First thing, get rid of those entities and write the javascript normally. That should make it a lot easier to follow what's going on.

Comment: I found this code on a website. I'm not familiar with javascript coding. I need a code to preserve line breaks when text is copied from my website. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection is being copied as plain text, to preserve the line breaks and formatting, you must get the selected text as HTML.

<kbd>[**JSFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/XKjNz/9/)</kbd>

JavaScript code:

```
function addLink() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();

    var htmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; ++i) {
        htmlDiv.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
    }
    var selectionHTML = htmlDiv.innerHTML;

    var pagelink = "<br/><br/>Read more: http://www.stackoverflow.com/ <br/>";
    var copytext = selectionHTML + pagelink;

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(newdiv); }, 0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
```

Comment: Thank you acdcjunior! This is what i was searching for. But i still don't know what to do. When i remove this code, the line breaks are preserved, when i put it back, text is selecting inline. I will keep searching. Thank you all

Comment: Did you change the `var copytext = selectionHTML + pagelink;             // <---- changed line` line as well? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: To understand me go to http://bancuricubarbatisifemei.blogspot.com/ and copy some text and paste it somewhere to see what happens.

Comment: I forgot, copy more lines, not just one

Comment: Yeah, I did. Right now the line breaks are not preserved. Did you add my modified code?

Comment: i gent an error on this line and i can not save template  for (var i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; ++i) {

Comment: I get "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup" on that line of code

Comment: I found the problem i replaced < with &lt; . Thank you so so much . Now works perfect :D Thank you all again. Stackoverflow best site :D

Answer (score 0):

You somehow missed a few quotes, believing [this](http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text), is where it came from.

Guess it works as you intend, after following corrections ([Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WwE7V/)):

```
function addLink() {
        var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var pagelink = '< br/> < br/> Mai multe Bancuri pe: http://bancuricubarbatisifemei.blogspot.com/ <br/>'; 
        var copytext = selection + pagelink;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';
        body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 0);
    }

document.oncopy = addLink;
```

---

***EDIT:***

Try using `pre` instead of `div` & newline character ('**\n**') to preserve line breaks. ([Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WwE7V/1/))

```
function addLink() {
        var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var pagelink = '\n\nMai multe Bancuri pe: http://bancuricubarbatisifemei.blogspot.com/\n'; 
        var copytext = selection + pagelink;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('pre');
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';
        body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 0);
    }

document.oncopy = addLink;
```

Comment: the code is working properly but there is another issue. The text is copied inline and the line breaks are ignored. I want to preserve the line breaks when the text is copied. Thank you

Comment: Please see the updated demo, the line breaks are now preserved.

Comment: To understand me go to http://bancuricubarbatisifemei.blogspot.com and copy some lines of text and paste it somewhere to see what happens