# How can I add line breaks when copying & pasting list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have an extra line break put in between each list item when someone copies the text from my site, since the bullet points don't copy. How can I do that?

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text) just tells you how to add code to the beginning and/or end of copied text, I'd like to add code in between list items!

The code is pretty simple:

```
<div>
  <li>This is the first paragraph.</li>
  <li>This is the second.</li>
  <li>This is the third.</li>
</div>

<textarea>Copy &amp; paste here with breaks in between each list item.</textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cleo_not_chloe/pvn3ahtr/

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add extra info to copied web text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text)

Comment: I edited my question to explain why it's different!

Comment: so the question is not about copy/paste, the question is about breaking string and change it...

Comment: @Cleo how about use regex when someone do copy  ??

Comment: How does the user input get copied into the textarea?  As they type or onclick?

Comment: Not sure what regex is, or how to change a string. The text is just highlighted and copy & pasted into the box!

Comment: So you want to double each break line. or extra break lines.

Comment: Yes, @MamdouhFreelance.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/pvn3ahtr/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

- Use `.on("copy", callback)` to detect user copied a text using mouse
  or keyboard (`Ctrl + c`).
- Use `window.getSelection()` to get selected text and customize it as
  you like remove, add or replace text. here i used
  `.replace(/\n/g,"\n\n")` to double each break line.
- Use `.on("paste", callback)` event to set `#textarea` value with your
  customized copied text.
- `<textarea>` should populated by plain text so use `.val()` not `.innerHTML` and `.html()`.

```js
//create global variable to store copied text.
var s;
//listen to copy for your element
$("#text").on("copy", function() {
  //get selected text while coping  
  s = window.getSelection().toString();
  //customize breaklines to be double
  s = s.replace(/\n/g, "\n\n");

  //add break line to the end and more text
  s += "\n" + "- More text says you are welcome";
  //HTML will displays as plain text in textarea
  s += "\n" + "- <p>Hello world</p>";

});
// listen to paste
$("#textarea").on("paste", function() {
  //set value with your customized copied text
  $("#textarea").val(s);
  return false;
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#savebox {
  float: right;
}
#textarea {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
  <ul>
    <li>This is the first paragraph.</li>
    <li>This is the second.</li>
    <li>This is the third.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="savebox">
  <textarea id="textarea">Copy &amp; paste here with breaks in between each list item.</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I have another situation where I do want to add text into the pasted text, like the other question I linked to. Your codes don't seem to work together, though. Do you know how to combine them? I've updated my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cleo_not_chloe/pvn3ahtr/5/

Comment: @Cleo You want to add HTML tags?

Comment: I don't know, will that allow both things to happen? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @Celo your fiddle used `.innerHTML` witch print your copied and customized text as html and its not targeted textbox. But here i used `.val()` witch print your HTML tags as plain text. see updated. and tell me you want to add extra text contains html for example clickable link inside textarea ?

Comment: No, I think this should be good! Thank you, I really appreciate the explanatory comments! Helps me learn!

Comment: @Celo You are appreciated :)