# Auto genrated link in compose box

Tags: email, meta-tags

[image]

Hi here I don't know exact title for this, but I will try explain you what exact I want. 
1.In my attached screen contains Email compose Box, in that I pasted just
https://www.iconfinder.com/. link. with that link title, Some description, Top border, Bottom border , Close button showing.(Highlighted with red border ) Same with https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/15971ff43d0599ff?compose=15971d7b6a9fc3d3

Here I want to know that, how to generate that extra content same to my Website.

Comment: Consider it duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4777746/234110

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add extra info to copied web text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text)

Answer (score 0):

Start using og meta tags (Open Graph) such as:

```
<meta name="description" content="Your Desc">
<meta property="og:title" content="Sample Title">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site">
<meta property="og:description" content="Your Desc">
<meta property="og:image" content="Image, if any">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/">
```

Add them in the head section of your HTML
You can find the details about it here: http://ogp.me/