# How to format selected/copied html content without javascript?

Tags: html, css, clipboard

In my particular case, I have a reusable component that displays a formatted weight (e.g. "12 kg 560 g").

The html that makes that up exists in DOM without any whitespace.  But when formatted looks something like:

```html
<span class="weight">
  <span>12</span>
  <span>kg</span>
  <span>560</span>
  <span>g</span>
</span>
```

That gets styled with CSS to add spacing to what's rendered.  But when I copy that text from chrome and paste it as text, it comes out as "12kg560g".

I'm aware I can add whitespace to solve this particular issue, but what if I want an entirely alternate representation?  For example: "12 KG. 560 G. (123.123 LBS.)".

The img tag has the alt attribute which browsers treat as the text representation.  Why isn't this a global attribute? Is there any way (without using javascript) to help the browser format the selected elements when copied?

Edit: After reviewing the html spec and thinking on this, it's pretty safe to say it's not possible.  Selecting arbitrary portions of a web page and copying/pasting as text just sucks

Comment: How are you doing the copying?

Comment: @AHaworth nothing special.  just highlighting on the screen and Ctrl/Cmd+C

Answer (score 0):

This should work, set the clipboard event data.
More info: [How to add extra info to copied web text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text)

```js
function changeContent(elem, content) {
  elem.addEventListener("copy", evt => {
    evt.clipboardData.setData("text/html", content(elem.innerHTML));
    evt.preventDefault();
  });
}

changeContent(document.querySelector("p"), content => `${content} foo bar 123 abcd <br> more multiline stuff <br> <h1> html yay </h1>`);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test copy content</h1>
<p>Lorem <u>ipsum</u> dolor sit <b>amet</b>, consectetur <i>adipiscing</i> elit.</p>
<h1>Try to paste here</h1>
<div contenteditable></div>
```