# Select-copy from a web page adds the page hyperlink to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

If you select a paragraph from eg http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/01/ipad-flash/ and paste it in word, you will notice that the link to that page has been added at the end of the paragraph.

Here is an example:

> Some of Apple’s promotional material
>   about the iPad implies the device’s
>   Safari browser can load Adobe Flash
>   content. However, demonstration units
>   of the tablet, including the one
>   presented by Steve Jobs, could not,
>   and a consumer has already filed a
>   complaint to the Federal Trade
>   Commission alleging false advertising.
>
> Read More
>   http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/01/ipad-flash/#ixzz0f2nM0huW

How do they do that???

Also they add #ixzz0f2nM0huW at the end of the link and when you follow the page the text that was selected appears highlighted!

Is there a javascript library to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203082/injecting-text-when-content-is-copied-from-web-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They use [**Tynt Insight**](http://www.tynt.com/). It is a commercial JavaScript library which comes with a [free version](http://www1.tynt.com/pro-features) that includes the "attribution link" feature described in your question.

You can see it referenced in their HTML within the `<head>` tag:

```
<!-- Tynt Tracer> --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> tyntVariables = {"ap":"Read More"}; </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tcr.tynt.com/javascripts/Tracer.js?user=ac4i_23GOr3QjHab7jrHcU&s=112"></script>
```

As Tim Down noted in a comment above, [Anirvan gave a very good briefing on the internals of the Tynt script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203082/injecting-text-when-content-is-copied-from-web-page), in a separate Stack Overflow post.